# Get ID of last inserted record in oracle db

Tags: oracle

I want to retrieve the id of a newly inserted record with an auto incrementing id column (using the sequence and trigger method). What is the standard way to do this?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use the PL/SQL `RETURNING` clause:

```
insert into mytable (...) values (...)
returning id into v_id;
```

Comment: Does this work only in PL/SQL?  I get a syntax error with regular SQL.

Comment: Yes it is PL/SQL only

Comment: Can it be used in `execute immediate`?

Comment: @akshay Yes: `execute immediate 'insert into mytable (...) values (...)
returning id into :retval' using out v_id;`

Comment: This doesn't work for insert using a select due to possibility of inserting more than 1 row. I am still looking for a way to grab the most recently inserted id. Perhaps I can get it from the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

use the results.lastRowid to make a query on the same table like "SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE ROWID = :lastRowid"

lastRowid looks like
"AAAS/tAAFAAAA/QAAB"

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a bind to recovery the value.

```
. . .
const result = await connection.execute(
    `INSERT INTO mytable (mydata) VALUES ('Hello') RETURN myid INTO :id`,
    {id : {type: oracledb.NUMBER, dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT } }
);

console.log(result.outBinds.id);  // print the ID of the inserted row
```

https://node-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/sql_execution.html#getting-the-last-insert-id