# How do I do an insert in oracle, and get the ID of the inserted row?

Tags: sql, oracle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get ID of last inserted record in oracle db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131064/get-id-of-last-inserted-record-in-oracle-db)

I am brand new to oracle, having used SQL Server in the past. I have a stored procedure, and I am trying to do two INSERTs one after the other. The second INSERT requires the ID of the first INSERT. Could someone explain how to do it?

I'm seeing stuff about `SEQUENCE`s and `nextvalue/curval` ?

I guess in SQL Server I'd just declare a variable, and use `SCOPE_IDENTITY`, so I'd be looking to do that.

Comment: looks about right, but I can't figure out how to declare a variable, except in the procedure declaration.

Comment: Sounds right.  Did you try that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two possibilities. If you are using sequences for number generation, you can get the value from the sequence, like this:

```
select SequenceName.currval into AVariable from dual
```

or this

```
AVariable := SequenceName.currval;
```

But it's probably better to use the `returning` clause like this:

```
declare
  AVariable int;
begin
  insert into yourtable(columns) 
  values (values) 
  returning id into AVariable;
  
  insert into anotherTable(columns)
  values(AVariable, othervalues);
end;
```

This way, it will work regardless of implementation details. You don't have to know the name of the sequence, and it will also work with the later introduced *identity* columns.

The only thing it won't work for is views with an *instead of* trigger, but that's a special case altogether.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few approaches.  One option is to use the `RETURNING` clause, i.e.

```
DECLARE
  l_generated_id INTEGER;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO table_name( <<column list>> )
    VALUES( <<values list>>
    RETURNING <<name of primary key column>>
         INTO l_generated_id;
  INSERT INTO other_table( <<column list>> )
    VALUES( l_generated_id, <<other values>> );
END;
```

If you know that the primary key is populated via a sequence (with or without a trigger) and you know the name of that sequence, you can use the `sequence_name.currval` in your second `INSERT` statement (the first `INSERT` statement would, either directly or via a trigger reference the `sequence_name.nextval` to generate the new primary key).