# pl/sql oracle how to check or how to store the current value of a sequence

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to show the record after insert it on the table. However my primary key is a substring with a sequence, so I cant find a way to save this value ...this is my code

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON


ACCEPT MARQUE PROMPT "Entrez la marque de la moto " 
ACCEPT ANNEE PROMPT "Entrez l annee de la moto: " 
ACCEPT PRIX PROMPT "Entrez le prix de la moto: "

DECLARE


myMarque VARCHAR2(50):='&MARQUE';
myAnnee VARCHAR2(6):='&ANNEE';
myPrix NUMBER(6,2):=&PRIX;
lecode VARCHAR2(12);

BEGIN

    IF myAnnee = 2013 THEN

        INSERT INTO MOTO (CODE, MARQUE, ANNEE, PRIX) VALUES (UPPER(SUBSTR(myMarque, 1,3)||MASEQ.nextval), myMarque, myAnnee, myPrix);
        COMMIT; 

    ELSIF myAnnee = 2014 THEN

        INSERT INTO MOTO (CODE, MARQUE, ANNEE, PRIX) VALUES (UPPER(SUBSTR(myMarque, 1,3)||MASEQ.nextval), myMarque, myAnnee, myPrix);
        COMMIT;

    ELSIF myAnnee = 2015 THEN

        INSERT INTO MOTO (CODE, MARQUE, ANNEE, PRIX) VALUES (UPPER(SUBSTR(myMarque, 1,3)||MASEQ.nextval), myMarque, myAnnee, myPrix);
        COMMIT;

    ELSIF myAnnee = 2016 THEN

        INSERT INTO MOTO (CODE, MARQUE, ANNEE, PRIX) VALUES (UPPER(SUBSTR(myMarque, 1,3)||MASEQ.nextval), myMarque, myAnnee, myPrix);
        COMMIT;
    ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Annee invalide SVP VERIFIEZ');
    END IF;



END;
/
```

In short what I need is to show the record after commit , any ideas? I tried to save the value in the variable lecode but it didnt work.

Comment: Perhaps you need last insert id http://stackoverflow.com/q/3131064/2298301?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `RETURNING` clause on your INSERTS, e.g.:

```
DECLARE
  strLast_code  MOTO.CODE%TYPE;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO MOTO
    (CODE, MARQUE, ANNEE, PRIX)
  VALUES
    (UPPER(SUBSTR(myMarque, 1,3)||MASEQ.nextval), myMarque, myAnnee, myPrix)
  RETURNING CODE INTO strLast_code;
END;
```

Comment: thank you it works fine. i didnt know u could do that

Answer (score 0):

`sequence_name.currval` will give the current value of sequence.

just like `sequence_name.nextval` you can get `sequence_name.currval`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to select directly from the database's metadata:

```
select last_number from all_sequences where sequence_name='MASEQ';
```