# Get the id of a newly inserted record using 'pg' gem

Tags: ruby, postgresql

I'm using the ['pg' gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/pg/versions/0.18.4) to work with postgresql from ruby. When inserting a new record, how can I get its serial id?

```
DB = PG.connect dbname: 'mydb', user: 'myuser'
res = DB.exec "insert into ..."
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found out you can add `returning id` to the query string. I.e.

```
DB = PG.connect dbname: 'mydb', user: 'myuser'
res = DB.exec "insert into ..."
id = res.first['id']
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3131073/165753)